# How to display child page as a modal popup in parent page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to dispaly a child page as a modal page in parent page.

I tried to achieve it but it was not successfull.

I was able to call the child page in modal popup but the page is redirected to child page and there it is displayed in a modal popup.

But what actually I want is to display the child page in parent page modal popup when clicked on the hyper link while the parent page is still present in the backgroud of the modal popup.

Can anyone please guide me to the solution.

Here is the code which I wrote.

**parent.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Parent Page </title>
</head>
<body >
 <a href="child.html" id = "parent"> Child  </a> 
</body>
</html>
```

**child.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title> Child Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
$( "#child" ).dialog();
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id ="child"> This is child page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

Two pages are manditory for the project and also I am trying to achieve this without using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

### Based on your comment i change the answer here so you can see.

```
 $('#linkID').click(function () {
       window.open("./childpage.html, "info6","resizable=no,scrollbars=1,status=yes,width=1000px,height=700px,menubar=0,toolbar=0");
 }
```

Im not sure if you need anything on the child page itself to react the way you want. But at least it opens a new window for you with the parent in behind i think.

Comment: 2 pages are manditory actually they are drupal tpl pages which are being called from call back functions in a custom module theme.

Comment: i have updated the answer for you. this is one of the ways we have done it.

Comment: but the page is still redirecting to the new page and no modal popup is being displayed. Are you using any additional libraries.